# Reject Process Action

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am having a portlet whose action method is called from a link send to through a mail.
But the problem is when the user clicks upon the link, process action is rejected by liferay(LR 6.2 ce ga 2).

I have tried putting `<add-default-resource>true</add-default-resource>`

and also setting the 
`portlet.add.default.resource.check.enabled=false
portlet.add.default.resource.check.whitelist= XXXXX_WAR_XXXXX`

properties in portal-ext.properties.

Is their anything that I am missing or something else I can do?

Comment: Explain better what rejected means? There is am error in the log?

Comment: Have you found a solution already? I fixed it by simply restarting my tomcat server. But now I have the same problem again and I can't seem to fix it...

Comment: Go through this link https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Authentication+Token  You can disable authentication token for a particular portlet by xml parameters. Further you can go through the https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/42009210

Comment: @Danish, this is fixed my issue. THX!